# How to hide file path output in pdb debugging mode in SublimeREPL?

Tags: settings, sublimetext, pdb

when I use the pdb debugging mode in SublimeREPL, I noticed that it outputs the file path, as shown below:

```
c:\users\xiakn\desktop\search.py(1)<module>() 
-> import requests 
(Pdb) n 
c:\users\xiakn\desktop\search.py(2)<module>() 
-> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
(Pdb)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to hide these path outputs?

```bash
-> import requests 
(Pdb) n 
-> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
(Pdb)
```

If so, how should I set it up? Thank you!

I have tried looking through the settings of SublimeREPL, but I couldn’t find any options related to hiding the file path output.Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.